Insert a new empty row above current row each time new values are entered
I need to create I need to create a log of sorts in Google Sheets.
I want to be able to make a log entry in an empty row, for example Row 2, and then when the entry is completed a new row is automatically inserted above it leaving row 2 empty to repeat the process with the next log entry.
Can this be done in Google Sheets?
Example
Initial Data

Row 2 is empty





A
B
C




1
Name
Value
Id


2





3
John
123
a1


4
Paul
456
b2


5
George
789
c3



New Entry Added

Data is entered in Row 2





A
B
C




1
Name
Value
Id


2
Ringo
123
as


3
John
123
a1


4
Paul
456
b2


5
George
789
c3



Desired Result

after completing the entry, a new row is inserted above
Existing data is shifting down by one row
Row 2 is ready for the next entry.





A
B
C




1
Name
Value
Id


2





3
Ringo
123
as


4
John
123
a1


5
Paul
456
b2


6
George
789
c3




This user ticks a checkbox on row 2 when the data entry is complete and they'd like the script to run.
Data in any other row can be freely edited at any time and will not trigger the script. This includes toggling or even removing the checkbox on any other row than 2.

function onEdit(e) {
  
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var editedrow = range.getRow();
  var editedvalue = e.value;
  
  if ( editedrow === 2 && editedvalue === "TRUE"){
    // the checkbox on row#2 was ticked.
    sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
    
  }
  return;
}


Screenshot

